# Integrating a real nasty!

Tags: integration

I came across this beast

$$\int_{0}^{\pi} \ln(1-2a \cos{x} +a^2)\cos{nx} \, dx $$

where $n=1,2,3,...$ and $a$ is an arbitrary real. Can this be down WITHOUT contour integration?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For $|a|<1$, we have
$$
I'(a)=2\int_0^\pi \frac{\cos nx(a-\cos x)}{1-2a\cos x+a^2}dx=\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{\cos nx(a-\cos x)}{1-2a\cos x+a^2}dx.
$$ Using the Fourier series $\displaystyle\frac1{1-a^2}\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty a^{|k|}e^{ikx}  = \frac{1}{1-2a\cos x+a^2}$, we have for $n\ge 1$
$$\begin{align*}
I'(a)&=\frac1{4(1-a^2)}\sum_{k\in\Bbb Z} a^{|k|}\int_0^{2\pi}e^{ikx}(e^{inx}+e^{-inx})(2a-e^{ix}-e^{-ix}) dx\\&=\frac{\pi}{2(1-a^2)}\sum_{k\in\Bbb Z} a^{|k|}\left(2a\mathbf1_{\{|k|=n\}}-\mathbf1_{\{|k|=n+1\}}-\mathbf1_{\{|k|=n-1\}}\right)\\&=\frac{\pi}{2(1-a^2)}\left( 4a^{n+1}-2a^{n+1}-2a^{n-1}\right)\\&=-\pi a^{n-1},
\end{align*}$$ which implies that $\displaystyle I(a)=-\frac{\pi a^n}{n} +I(0)=-\frac{\pi a^n}{n}$. For $|a|>1$, use
$$
I(a)=\int_{0}^{\pi} \left(\ln\left(1-2 \frac{\cos{x}}a +\frac1{a^2}\right)+2\ln a\right)\cos{nx} \ dx
$$ to obtain
$$
I(a)=-\frac{\pi a^{-n}}{n}.
$$

Comment: Nice (+1). Where can one see a proof of that interesting Fourier series?

Comment: @clathratus Thank you :) In fact, it even has a famous name [Poisson kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_kernel) in complex/harmonic analysis.